# how to insert selected asp.net c# checkbox value to the sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have four check box.but i can not insert selected check box value my SQL table.

my code:-

```
protected void btnADDSAVE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SONU-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Prashant-Online_Store-DB; Integrated Security=true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_addnewproduct";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = checkbox.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = checkbox1.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = checkbox3.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = checkbox4.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Add new product..");

        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("Not add new product.?");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message after the execution of code?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Does your stored procedure accept 2 parameters or 4 parameters? Are you trying to call the procedure only once or twice?

Comment: Your procedure will add text of your checkbox everytime regardless whether your checkbox is checked or not. Because You do not check whether check box is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

As SpiderCode has pointed out, you are trying to get the checkbox text value without checking if the checkbox is checked or not.

use conditional operator to insert the value if checked else insert empty string;

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = checkbox.IsChecked ? checkbox.Text.Trim() : string.Empty;
```